# Auto run script on LInux

Tags: bash, petalinux

I am trying to understand why my script hasn't fully run on startup. I am working on embedded linux (USing petalinux). my script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello PetaLinux World"

ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.120
```

Unfortunately, i see that only echo command has been executed, and I see 'Hello PetaLinux World' on boot log.
When trying to run the script manually **after boot** ifconfig is also executed.
Is there a reason for ifconfig command (or any other commands) not to be executed while boot?

**update**
i modified the script:

```
    #!/bin/sh
 
echo "Hello PetaLinux World"
 
# Use the full path to ifconfig and capture errors
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.120 > /tmp/ifconfig.log 2>&1
 
# Check for errors and log them
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error running ifconfig. Check /tmp/ifconfig.log for 
details."
fi
```

in boot i see:

```
Hello PetaLinux World
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
Configuring network interfaces... udhcpc: started, v1.31.0
```

when checking ifconfig log i get:

```
root@brm1553_intr:~# cat /tmp/ifconfig.log .bash_history
ifconfig
rclear
ckear
clear
reboot
```

Comment: How / when is the script run "on startup"? Is `eth0` already available when the script runs?

Comment: We need enough information to reproduce the problem ourselves. That means, in this case, the same steps you used to install the script to run at boot. (Some general background for those of us who don't know Petalinux would be helpful, too: there are good options for how to do this on systemd-based distros, where you can say something needs to run `After: network-online.target`, f/e; but folks who don't know Petalinux don't _know_ if it's systemd-based). (For more details on that, see https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/)

Comment: Even though your question misses a lot of details - I would say if you see the effect  of `echo` call than there is a very high chance that the next line was also executed. The question is how do you know it wasn't executed?

Comment: Why not redirect stderr to a file and check what it says after boot?

Comment: I hoped it is similar to Ubuntu but to explain Petalinux and Xilinx..  i use ifconfig command after boot to see that the script hasn't executed this command.  Petalinux It is similar to yocto.. i built Linux from sources (in ubuntu). i use command to add auto run script: https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2020.2-English/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide/Application-Auto-Run-at-Startup. It consists of the script along with bitbake file.  
DevSolar - eth0 and a lot of other peripherals are configured in device tree and packaged together to create Linux image.

Comment: to make some of this advice explicit, how about `/full/path/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.120 > /tmp/ifconfigTestStdOutStdErr.txt 2>&1` and see what is in there. Good luck.

Comment: The root cause is that random ad-hoc scripts on startup have never worked properly on any system. That’s why `systemd` is quite an important improvement. [Petalinux has it](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide/Systemv-to-Systemd), it seems. You should use **`systemd-networkd`** instead of random scripts. `systemd` tracks dependencies among system components, system state transitions (suspend / resume) and can do many things scripts will never be able to do. And it keeps logs properly. Side note: One should avoid `ifconfig` in favor of `ip`.

Answer (score -1):

System startup scripts, such as CRON, do not have environment variables defined as they are in the console. So the solution is usually to put the full path to the executable, or define the PATH variable before executing the command.